# How to get 30 minute time slots python2.7

Tags: python, list, datetime

I'm currently able to get 1 hour time slots between two numbers, but I would like to get time slots of 30 minute intervals.

my full code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
def get_time_slotes():

    work_times = [u'08:00', u'17:00']
    appointments = [u'12:30', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'9:30']

    # list_of_times = [u'08:00', u'12:30', u'13:00', u'09:00', u'9:30', u'17:00']
    work_time_convert = sorted(datetime.strptime(x.encode('utf-8'),'%H:%M').time() for x in work_times)
    appointments_convert = sorted(datetime.strptime(x.encode('utf-8'),'%H:%M').time() for x in appointments)

    # I COMMENTED THIS LINE OUT AND COPIED IT AS IT REMOVEs THE APPOINTMENT CONVERTED TIMES FROM THE LIST.
    # res = [x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in sorted(set(time(x,0,0,0) for x in range(min(work_time_convert).hour, max(work_time_convert).hour + 1)) - set(appointments_convert))]

    #IN THIS QUESTION I WOULD LIKE THE OUTPUT OF THIS LINE TO BE IN 30 MIN INTERVALS RATHER THAN 1 HOUR
    res = [x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in sorted(set(time(x,0,0,0) for x in range(min(work_time_convert).hour, max(work_time_convert).hour + 1)))]
    print("The list of missing elements : " + str(res))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_time_slotes()
```

The code that finds missing time slots between the two numbers is:

```
res = [x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in sorted(set(time(x,0,0,0) for x in range(min(work_time_convert).hour, max(work_time_convert).hour + 1)))]
```

Which outputs:

```
The list of missing elements : ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00']
```

I would like it to be:

```
The list of missing elements : ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '9:30', '10:30', ...] # and so forth
```

Once I get the list I just remove the appointment times from it leaving me with the available times left.

Comment: your code gives some error change the code

Comment: @guru code is for python2.7 (constraints)

Comment: oh okay cool i ran that code in python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code which generates the slots to just

```
res = [time(t,0,0,0).strftime("%H:%M") for t in range(min(work_time_convert).hour, max(work_time_convert).hour)]
```

From there it's fairly simple to extend it to include the 30 minute time by generating time values for a minute value of `0` or `30`:

```
res = [time(t,m,0,0).strftime("%H:%M") for t in range(min(work_time_convert).hour, max(work_time_convert).hour) for m in [0, 30]]
```

Output:

```
['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30',
 '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30',
 '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30',
 '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', 
 '16:00', '16:30']
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

When a hour consists of a whole number of intervals you can just use two loops:

```
In [2]: [time(h, m).strftime('%H:%M') for h in range(8, 17) for m in (0, 30)]
Out[2]:
['08:00',
 '08:30',
 '09:00',
 '09:30',
 '10:00',
 '10:30',
 '11:00',
 '11:30',
 '12:00',
 '12:30',
 '13:00',
 '13:30',
 '14:00',
 '14:30',
 '15:00',
 '15:30',
 '16:00',
 '16:30']
```

For intervals like `23 minutes` you can use the following code:

```
In [3]: [time(m // 60, m % 60).strftime('%H:%M') for m in range(8 * 60, 17 * 60, 23)]
Out[3]:
['08:00',
 '08:23',
 '08:46',
 '09:09',
 '09:32',
 '09:55',
 '10:18',
 '10:41',
 '11:04',
 '11:27',
 '11:50',
 '12:13',
 '12:36',
 '12:59',
 '13:22',
 '13:45',
 '14:08',
 '14:31',
 '14:54',
 '15:17',
 '15:40',
 '16:03',
 '16:26',
 '16:49']
```

Comment: I like your take on the 23 minutes! I will incorporate it into my code.